# stringByAppendingPathComponent no more valid for swift2

Tags: swift2

NSTemporaryDirectory().stringByAppendingPathComponent("Library/Caches") which method can replace it & please give sentence for that 
thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution is a simple type cast to `NSString`

```
(NSTemporaryDirectory() as NSString).stringByAppendingPathComponent("Library/Caches")
```

Other standard folders like `NSHomeDirectory()` can be specified with `URLForDirectory:inDomain:appropriateForURL:create` of `NSFileManager` to be able to use the path modification methods of `NSURL`.